# Host sending packet to its own address (non localhost)

Tags: ip

let's consider a host with a public IP address. The host sends an IP packet with Destination Address set to its own address.

Is the packet physically sent over a link or is it only sent within the host just like it was sent to localhost address?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you send to a local interface the traffic will remain local to the host, as if you sent to the loopback, it will not exit the host and route back in.  On a Mac, the routing table shows lo0 as the outgoing interface.